# On removing store view, Does Magento remove its associated URLs(Generated)

Tags: magento2, magento-1.8, magento-1, url-rewrite

Need information regarding Magento setup.

> On removing store view, Does Magento remove its associated
>   URLs(Generated: Core_URL_Rewrite etc) ?

Thanks